C++20 std::views and caching
I am reading the C++20, Complete Guide book.
I am going through the caching mechanism of views.
There is the following statement:

Modifying leading elements of ranges (changing their value or inserting/deleting elements) may
invalidate views if and only if begin() has already been called before the modification.

First question is why this is invalidate since begin() is not modified.
std::vector vec{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto biggerThan2 = [](auto v){ return v > 2; };
auto vVec = vec | std::views::filter(biggerThan2);
print(vVec); // OK: 3 4
++vec[1];
vec[2] = 0; // vec becomes 1 3 0 4
print(vVec); // OOPS: 0 4;

If this invalided I expect that accessing list in similar way will be invalided as well
std::list lst{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
auto c = std::views::counted(lst.begin(), 5);
print(c); // 1 2 3 4 5
lst.insert(++lst.begin(), 0); // insert new second element in lst
print(c); // 1 0 2 3 4


Its says may invalidate views. list specifically doesn't invalidate existing iterators when inserting new elements. So perhaps it just works?

In general any instance of std::views adapters is for one time use only. A second time may cause trouble. Ideal usage is as prvalue-only.

This is undefined behavior according to [[range.filter.iterator#1]]:

Modification of the element a filter_view::​​iterator denotes is
permitted, but results in undefined behavior if the resulting value
does not satisfy the filter predicate.



why this is invalidate since begin() is not modified.

My first point is perhaps a nit-pick: begin() is a member function. So unless you're editing the actual library code that implemented it, then you're not modifying it.

But, that aside, the first code segment calls the view's begin() when it calls print. This is when the caching is done. vVec.begin() was determined to be vec.begin() + 2 (for vec at that point). So, it will not check that the value still passes the filter. It will blindly accept it, and only begin checking whether values pass the filter for the next element of the vector it's viewing. Of course, it won't be able to check if the iterator has become invalid either (it hasn't in our case). This means that correct behaviour in this case is determined by whether the iterator to the first element that passes the filter immediately before the first call to the view's begin() remains the same iterator that points to the first element that passes the filter immediately before any subsequent calls to the view's begin().
Here's an example of the same situation working, because the first element to pass the filter (biggerThan2) on the first call to our view's begin() would still pass the filter on the second call to begin():
  std::vector vec{1, 2, 3, 4};
  auto biggerThan2 = [](auto v){ return v > 2; };
  auto vVec = vec | std::views::filter(biggerThan2);
  print(vVec); // OK: 3 4
  vec[2] = 9;
  vec[3] = 0; // vec becomes 1 3 9 0
  print(vVec); // OK: 9

demo

In your second example it worked, partially because inserting into a std::list doesn't invalidate its iterators (as it does for std::vector), but the pertinant point is that only some views do caching on begin() (views::filter is the only one I know of) and views::counted doesn't have this behaviour - its begin() member function is const.
If we used an std::list with a views::filter like in your first example we could get the same bad behaviour:
std::list list{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto biggerThan2 = [](auto v){ return v > 2; };
auto vList = list | std::views::filter(biggerThan2);
print(vList); // OK: 3 4

auto it = list.begin();

++it;
*it = 3;
++it;
*it = 0;
// vec becomes 1 3 0 4

print(vList); // OOPS: 0 4;

demo

As an aside, there's so many quirky "gotchas" in std::views that I'd leave it to the last topic to study.

I am confused why the second example with vector works. Can you explain to me in more details?

@getsoubl, views::filter doesn't cache everything. It just caches the begin position, which we haven't changed upon its second call to begin().

The emphasis in that quote is on may; it depends on the view in question.
std::views::filter is quite special because it needs to search for the first element that satisfies the predicate when begin() is called.
[range.filter.view] says the following:

constexpr iterator begin();

Preconditions: pred_.has_value() is true.
Returns: {*this, ranges​::​find_if(base_, ref(*pred_))}.
Remarks: In order to provide the amortized constant time complexity required by the range concept when filter_view models forward_range, this function caches the result within the filter_view for use on subsequent calls.

As a consequence of this remark, you can modify the range however you like prior to the first call to begin(), but after having called it once, you must not invalidate the iterator cached inside the view, and you must not modify the elements so that the result of .begin() for the filter_view would change (see [range.filter.iterator] p1), which is what vec[2] = 0; does.
std::views::counted is harmless by comparison.
For a given std::list, it simply creates a std::subrange (see [range.counted] p2.3).
std::list doesn't invalidate iterators on insertion, so the subrange remains safe to use.
